# GVim Cygwin Ballooneval color scheme

Tags: colorscheme, cygwin

Currently I am using GVim on Cygwin 64-Bit Windows 7 with Pyclewn plugin for debugging C/C++ Application.

Whenever the balloon eval tooltip pops-up the Color difference between the balloon background the underlying text content is too small to be easily readable.

I have tried setting the:

```
:highlight Tooltip guibg=white
```

as mentioned in the gvim help

```
:help gui-resources
```

But to no-avail.

**Update:** Kindly find the screenshot below of the balloon eval(marked in **Red** Circle):
[image: GVim Balloon Eval]

Comment: Consider adding .gif screenshots with your question, makes it a lot easier to understand the problem

Comment: Can anybody help me in this regard?